# QTextEdit render the text in all lowercase type automatically?

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt

Recently I made an application with PyQt on macOS.

I wrote a editor based on QTextEdit.

```
class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QTextEdit.__init__(self, parent)

    self.parent = parent
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    font = QFont()
    font.setFamily("Monaco")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.setFont(font)
```

However, when I type in this editor, it automatically converts all input letters to lowercase. In other words, I can't enter uppercase letters.

Any idea to fix this?

Here is my environment:

- pyqt 4.11
- Qt 4.8
- Python 2.7.9
- macOS 10.13.2

Comment: @Murphy I can not understand what is unclear for you here.

Comment: @Taz742 It's not unclear as far as code is provided, but is missing parts that may be important, e. g. the UI code/QML file. Additionally providing a [mcve] increases the chances of the question being answered, for the reasons given in the links.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty weird, because `QTextEdit` has no method to explicitly force casing. However, CSS2 has a `text-transform` property, and your TextEdit behaves as if it was set to

```
text-transform: lowercase;
```

I would try setting it to `none`, this way:

```
    def initUI(self):
            font = QFont()
            font.setFamily("Monaco")
            font.setPointSize(14)
            self.setFont(font)
            self.setStyleSheet("text-transform: none;")
```

Comment: Thx. I will give it a try.

Comment: This way still doesn't work for me. I don't know why. It seems to be a pyqt4 problem. After I upgrade to pyqt5, this problem solved.